# Left align element with centered and variable width element in top row

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to find a way to left align `<p>` with centered `<img>` in the top.

As images are centered and my page contains **different images with different widths**, it seems to be a bit challenging.

Here is my html structure:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 my-auto">
        <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
          <img class="img-fluid d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center" id="image-id">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        SOME CONTENT
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse collapse-information">
      <div class="row row-collapse m-0">
        <!--What I want to be left aligned with img tag-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A way to do it would be to get the distance between image's div and border of centered image and to report this measure as a left-margin on the element I want to be aligned.

To solve it, I tried to use margin measurments based on window width but it as not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working to have a clean question, I went through https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft.

The interresting part is that, javascript allows a dynamic measurement I can also dynamically attribute to other elements.

```js
// get left offset
var leftDistanceLogo = document.querySelector("#image-id").offsetLeft;

// assing as margin to the following element
document.querySelector('.row-collapse').style.marginLeft = leftDistanceLogo + "px";
```

Last interesting point, this code should wait until the end of page loading (otherwise offet will be equal to 0), so I called it in a structure like:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        var leftDistanceLogo = document.querySelector("#image-id").offsetLeft;
        document.querySelector('.row-collapse').style.marginLeft = leftDistanceLogo + "px";
    }, 0);
});
```